# Apache rewrite rule for normalizing case

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I run a web-accessible linguistic database on a server. The file `lexirumah` in the document root of my server contains a WSGI python script serving the application.

I want the application to be available on all matches, independent of case, of `http://www\.example\.eu/lexirumah?/?`. Currently, I am using the following `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.eu/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^lexirumah?$ http://www.example.eu/lexirumah/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^lexiruma/$ http://www.example.eu/lexirumah/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^LexiRumah/$ http://www.example.eu/lexirumah/ [L,R=301]

Options +ExecCGI
<Files "lexirumah">
SetHandler fcgid-script
</Files>
```

When I change the last `RewriteRule` to

```
RewriteRule ^LexiRumah/$ http://www.example.eu/lexirumah/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

I get an infinitite number of redirects. I want to keep the 301 status for the non-canonical URLs, so I tried

```
RewriteRule ^lexirumah/$ http://www.example.eu/lexirumah/ [L]
RewriteRule ^lexirumah?$ http://www.example.eu/lexirumah/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^lexiruma/$ http://www.example.eu/lexirumah/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^LexiRumah/$ http://www.example.eu/lexirumah/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

leading to an internal server error. (Presumably the infinite redirection loop that was caught by my browser previously now happens inside `mod_rewrite`?)

Now I have changed the rules to use a `RewriteCond` to skip the case normalization when it is already lowercase.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lexirumah/$
RewriteRule ^LexiRumah/$ http://www.example.eu/lexirumah/ [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^lexirumah?$ http://www.example.eu/lexirumah/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^lexiruma/$ http://www.example.eu/lexirumah/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

Does this set of rules do what I want it to do, or are there any hidden pitfalls that I need to take into account?

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

**Yes, your set of rules does what you expect**.

Note, though, that you could simply use `^lexirulah/$` in first `RewriteRule`, since you include the `NC` flag. As a consequence, the matching will be case-insensitive (`No Case`). Official documentation of `NC` flag can be found [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc).

Also, you don't need a full url (host included) to redirect. You can directly use `RewriteRule ^xxxx$ /lexirumah/ [L,R=301,NC]` for each rule.

## Your initial question

> When I change the last RewriteRule to
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^LexiRumah/$ http://www.example.eu/lexirumah/ [L,R=301,NC]
> ```
>
> I get an infinitite number of redirects.

If you think about it, it's easy to understand why you end up with an infinite loop. Since `NC` matches in case-insensitive mode, your redirect will always match your rule, again and again.